# SQL query in jreviews pages, joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

How can I "echo" a basic SQL query in Jreviews pages?  I'm using Joomla 2.5.

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(product) AS totalcount FROM my_table WHERE productid LIKE = 'sony'
```

Jreviews is based on PHP (like Joomla).

Expected result, example:

```
Sony product: 105
```

Answer (score 2):

Query is wrong

```
SELECT COUNT(product) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table 
WHERE productid LIKE '%sony%'
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(product) AS totalcount 
FROM my_table 
WHERE productid = 'sony'
```

but not `LIKE =`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the underlying version of Joomla you should be able to use something like this -

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM my_table
          WHERE productid = 'sony'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$count = $db->loadResult();

echo "<p>Sony product: $count</p>";
```

[JDatabase documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But, sorry for this stupid question, how can I convert results in HMTL? Thanks!

Comment: Just echo the result as I have in my updated answer. If you need something else then I suggest you update your question with more detail, including the code that you are trying to add it to.